# Book Identification: young adult sci-fi, I think it was published in the 60s or 70s

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

There was a book I read when I was a kid in the early 80s, and I can't remember what it was called.  It was a collection of short stories that were loosely connected.  Here is what I remember:

- The overall tone of the book was good against evil
- one of the stories talks about a group who are being attacked by 'space moss' , and they killed it by grabbing onto an external radio antenna, and the radio energy destroyed the moss.  I think they picked up the moss during a stopover on a planet, but I can't recall.
- one of heroes names is 'Dominic'
- Another story talks about an attack on a planet by pirate spaceships that traveled in single-file so only showed up as one silhouette
- I think one of the villains name was 'Incus(sp)'

I know that's vague, but that's all I can remember

Comment: "'space moss' (don't ask)" - surely we *should* ask, since any extra detail might help us in identifying your story?

Comment: Yep, there's a [tvTrope for that.](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FesteringFungus)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Black Star Chronicles" by by D.J. Arneson and Tony Tallarico

*A Madman is loose in the universe. Imperator Incus has vowed to rule the Seven Planets and bring an end to peace everywhere.
Is there nothing that can stop him? Will the ruler of Black Star succeed with his space conquest?
Only one ma can stop Incus. He is Dominic the Bold, commander of the Titans.
Who will win?*

Searching inside the [Google book](https://books.google.com/books?id=wozijonfCpUC) there is "space moss" and someone's instruction to pilots to

> Stay in a perfect single file. If they see only one dot on their radar
>   screens, they will think we're an asteroid.